# Синусы и косинусы, как объяснить?

Tags: геометрия

На данный момент я заканчиваю работу над стартапом, цель которого максимально просто объяснить математику/геометрию, но к сожалению встрял вопрос с геометрией, к примеру, C=90 градусов SIN A = 7/25, вопрос, найти cos A, я прекрасно знаю что тут просто нужно найти cos по формуле 1-sin в квадрате и всё, но на форуме мне постоянно задают вопрос: как их легко запоминать? Как им легко всё объяснить?

[image: Вот пример]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ мне кажется через геометрический круг
[image: Картинка взята из раздела тригонометрии в Wikipedia]

Comment: А только как легче всего объяснить ВСЮ суть синусов/косинусов? Большинство заданий с измененными условиями, к примеру, в одной нужно найти sin через tg, в другой tg через cos и т.д.

Comment: Привёл пример с кругом так как на личном опыте помню в школе давали какое угодно объяснения,через отношения сторон, но запомнилось только когда нарисовал круг и поигрался с углом треугольника.
Если сделать эту картинку анимированной  меняя угол (при этом лучше пользователю дать возможность самому "поиграться" с заданием угла) то это наглядно и вполне понятно, а как только sin/cos  будет задан то можно добавить более сложные элементы как на этой https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7b/Circle-trig7.svg

Comment: Самое простое - это запомнить с помощью единичного круга, что sin 30 градусов будет половинка. Остальное либо вычисляется, либо запоминается со временем...